# function that takes a command and a mode-map returning the bound string

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a command ie: `get-bounded-string` that is available that performs this?

```
(defun no-op () nil)

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd  "C-c C-7") 'no-op)
```

then

```
(get-bound-string dired-mode-map 'no-op)
=> "C-c C-7"
```

Comment: Since this is meant to invoke `no-op` as a command, its definition should contain the `(interactive)` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs has a `substitute-command-keys` function, which takes a format string and substitutes occurrences of specific escape substrings according to their type. Specifically, it replaces `\\[<command>]` with the keybinding for `<command>` *in the context of the current keymap*.

What you can do is run the function in the context of a temporary buffer with desired keymap set. It might look something like this:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (use-local-map dired-mode-map)
  (substitute-command-keys "\\[no-op]"))
```

You could, of course, wrap the above in a function definition.

Comment: oh wow. that's super impressive... though it's quite a round about way of doing it. What I'm looking to do is to be able to generate a hydra from a mode's keybindings. It's definitely a start but is is there something more efficient?

Comment: As a matter of fact there is. I just found out about it myself. You can do `(substitute-command-keys "\\<dired-mode-map>\\[no-op]")`.

Comment: oh this is awesome. thanks heaps.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: this looks something very similar to what I had in mind: https://gitlab.com/jjzmajic/hercules.el

Comment: Oh, I see. At first I was a bit mystified by the purpose of `hercules`, but the example scenario in the README cleared it up. Neat idea. So basically, you're providing a shortcut to a sequence of identically prefixed commands? What you could also do (perhaps you're already doing it?) is to have all the enabled prefixes available for viewing in case you didn't even remember which prefix you want to use. Something like a selector of user-defined prefixes.

Comment: I think what's really great about this approach is the fact that you get a Visual Aid for free. The most important thing are the key bindngs. So the steps are: 1. You define the key bindings you want for a mode. 2. You define using hercules a subset of bindings you want, and it generates a hydra that is consistent with those key bindings.

Answer (score 2):

You already accepted an answer as correct, but I interpreted your question differently, as wanting Elisp code that tells you what key(s) a given command is bound to in a given mode.

If you're interested in that, `where-is-internal` will do it for you.

For example, to find out what keys command `dired-mark` is bound to in Dired mode, use this:

`(where-is-internal 'dired-mark dired-mode-map)`

See the Elisp manual, node [Scanning Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Scanning-Keymaps.html).

Interactively, you have command `where-is`, bound to `C-h w`.  That tells you which keys a command is bound to in the *current buffer* (mode).